# How to use malloc to get memory address for pointer in c, then assign char array at that address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I am trying to create a string in C, which is just an array of data type char. I am trying to have a pointer and then assign the value of a char array. This is what I have so far:

```
char *string;
string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

// Now I have a pointer, so if I wanted to print out the pointer of the spot 
// in memory that is saved I can do the following:
printf("%p", string);

// That gives me the pointer, now I want to assign an array at that address

// *string gives me that data stored at the pointer
*string = "Array of chars?";
printf("%s", *string);
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong with that?

I need to use malloc unfortunately, but please feel free to tell me a better way to do this as well with along with the solution using malloc.

Thank you guys!

Comment: malloc returns a pointer of memory that is allocated on the heap.  In your case, you just need to copy the characters into the buffer after allocation.  Lookup strncpy, strcpy, or memcpy.

Comment: Since the first two lines won't even compile (not a good start), I think the first thing you're doing wrong is not studying pointers in the C language enough to begin effectively using them.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just threw out whatever was on the top of my head. I don't appreciate you not giving an answer and just shooting down my question.  Yes to get it to properly compile I would need to remove the []. I'll fix my question so maybe you can give answering it a shot. Sorry about that.

Comment: There you go. So . How much data does the string you're going to copy occupy, and how much did you actually allocate? After fixing your decls, you're not too far off. You need to allocate the appropriate amount of memory (and lose the `(char *)` cast; it isn't needed in C), then do what Paul suggested; lookup the `strcpy` family of functions. Also, `printf` using `%s` requires a `const char*` compatible argument; you're giving it a `char`. Maybe fix that too.

Comment: Well enough data to hold I don't know, some sort of char that probably is maybe a name or something. No bigger than 20 chars. The professor wants us to have a node that contains the attribute char *string; No clue on how big the size of the string should be. To be more specific I'm building a linkedlist where the nodes hold char *string.

Comment: The size of the string buffer allocation should be determined by the *length* of the string you're trying to copy +1 for the closing terminator. `strlen` will come in handy there (or just `strdup()` if allowed by your prof). If you're doing this in a linked list you're going to end up with two allocations per node (one for the node; one for the string field *in* the node). There are many examples of linked list node management on the web, not related to your question.

Comment: I've been searching on the web trying to find an example of an implementation using char[] but the examples I usually get are int, probably for the simplicity. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @WhozCraig printf does not require a const char* in C right? It is only in C++ I believe.

Comment: @ErikW The pointer doesn't have to be `const`, but it will be compliant regardless, as `char *` is convertible to `const char*`. Both C and C++ simply require the address of the initial element of sequence of `char` for `%s`. The const is up to you. There is no requirement the sequence be *writable*, thus `const` will suffice, and though it may at-first seem more restrictive, it is actually *less* so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the two variables you declared, you should write:

```
char* string = malloc(sizeof(char) * <insert number of chars plus one here>);
```

You should write:

```
string = "Array of chars";
printf("%s", string);
```

to print the string.

Comment: Does it matter where the * is? You have it right next to char?

Comment: @Miguel J. No, I just prefer to have it that way.

Comment: So right now with your implementation the code looks like this: string[  ] ----> [Array of chars] right?

Comment: If I want to change the pointer I would use *string = new pointer location in memory and to change data at pointer would I use string = "new array of chars"?

Comment: @MiguelJ. Well, you should use free(string) first to clear the memory at the current location. Then you can assign it to another memory location like this: string = <insert name of pointer here>;